# Interacting with windows messages with command based compiler

Tags: c, winapi, command-line, windows-messages

This is probably a stupid question but here it goes.

Suppose you are interacting with a Driver API. You are using C and doing entirely via command prompt. No GUI. Is it possible to recieve and handle windows message in such files?

I mean, everywhere, I am using windows handle as NULL. I have no idea if this is possible or even makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use GetMessage or PeekMessage you don't need any windows in your thread: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> The thread to which the message is posted must have created a message
>   queue, or else the call to PostThreadMessage fails.
>
> Use the following method to handle this situation.
>
> Create an event object, then create
>   the thread.
>
> Use the WaitForSingleObject function to wait for the event
>   to be set to the signaled state before calling PostThreadMessage.
>
> In
>   the thread to which the message will be posted, call PeekMessage as
>   shown here to force the system to create the message queue:
>
> PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_USER, WM_USER, PM_NOREMOVE)
>   >
>   Set the event,
>   to indicate that the thread is ready to receive posted messages. The
>   thread to which the message is posted retrieves the message by calling
>   the GetMessage or PeekMessage function. The hwnd member of the
>   returned MSG structure is NULL.

Comment: And do some reading about the `console` and `gui` subsystems. You probably want to use the GUI subsystem.